# Random me genera el mismo resultado varias veces

Tags: c#, random

```
string nombre;
    public string gen2(int Name_Len)
    {
        string[] abc = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

        if (Name_Len >= 5)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c <= Name_Len; c++)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                nombre += abc[rand.Next(0, 24)];
            }
        }
        return nombre;
    }
 gen2(6);
```

Esto me esta dando como resultado por EJ: JJJJJJ || KKKKKK... etc. y en cada ejecución, se repite bastante cada elemento, es decir es muy probable que me vuelva a salir JJJJJJ, KKKKKK, habia leído algo que Random genera en funcion del tiempo del pc, algo así. Disculpen mi consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, el problema es que creaba el objeto dentro del método, solo debí hacer esto:

```
string nombre;
Random rand = new Random();//Fuera del Método
public string gen2(int Name_Len)
{
    string[] abc = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

    if (Name_Len >= 5)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c <= Name_Len; c++)
        {
            //aqui estaba el Método
            nombre += abc[rand.Next(0, 24)];
        }
    }
    return nombre;
}
```

gen2(6);

Como respuesta si a alguien mas le sucede ;)

Comment: Aunque tu programa funciona de manera correcta, si quieres apurar un poco mas y asegurarte de que el Random se inicializa cada vez con una semilla diferente te recomiendo que pongas: Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond) . Por otro lado, el metodo Random para generar numeros aleatorios no es nada aconsejable para sistemas que deban ser seguros o criticos.